# Is there a way of querying how much of the API limit has been used?

Tags: discussion, rate-limit

Twitter has the ability as part of its API to query the current rate limit status. Going to [this](http://api.twitter.com/1/account/rate_limit_status.json) url will show you how many requests can be made before the limit is reached:

```
{"remaining_hits":150,  
 "hourly_limit":150,
 "reset_time_in_seconds":1274399014,
 "reset_time":"Thu May 20 23:43:34 +0000 2010"}
```

Requests to this url also do not count towards the limit.

Is there a similar ability with the SO API? If so, how is it done?

Comment: Should be tagged as feature-request.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I imagine a `/status` method would not be too hard, and is crucial in both testing and deploying applications.

Imagine an application that updates a database with new questions. It can query the `/status` method to correctly time it's calls so that it can make it through the day.

I would also consider whether this call should count towards the limit. Twitter, for instance, doesn't count a `/status` call against the limit.

---

Actually, it is included in all headers. From Chrome, here is what I get back:

> Cache-Control:private
>   Connection:keep-alive
>   Content-Encoding:gzip
>   Content-Length:5158
>   Content-Type:application/json;
>   charset=utf-8 Date:Thu, 20 May 2010
>   23:18:10 GMT Server:nginx
>   X-AspNet-Version:2.0.50727
>   X-AspNetMvc-Version:2.0
>   **X-RateLimit-Current:298**
>   **X-RateLimit-Max:300**

Comment: I'd agree that it shouldn't count towards the limit, otherwise just simply asking if you are over the limit could put you over the limit :)

Comment: I thought that was the case.

Comment: I think that these RateLimit headers should be documented. 

Also, I believe that Twitter's API, for example, uses this header approach, as well as a `/status` method. Shouldn't we implement the latter, too (having `/status` not count against the rate limit, of course)?

Comment: I dislike the header method.  I really think this should be added to `/status` as well.